# How to convert multiple .json files into multiple .db files with sqllite3 and pandas?

Tags: python, json, database, pandas, sqlite

I have 11 .json files (2006.json, 2007.json, ... ,2016.json) stored in a directory called /arbetsformedlingen. What I want is to convert all these 11 .json files into 11 .db files, e.g (2006.db, 2007.db, ... ,2016.db). I'm using jupyter (ipython) notebook and python 3.6 (py36). The following code takes all the .json files and converts it into one single file called arbetsformedlingen.db (which is a to large file).

```
    import pandas as pd
    import sqlite3
    import uuid

    conn=sqlite3.connect('/Users/mo/PBL/arbetsformedlingen/arbetsformedlingen.db')  
    conn.execute('drop table if exists stillinger')

    for year in range(2006,2017,1):

        file = '/Users/mo/PBL/arbetsformedlingen/' + str(year) + '.json'
        df = pd.read_json(file, lines=True)

        guids = []
        for i in range(0,len(df)):
        guids.append(str(uuid.uuid4()))

        guids_s = pd.Series(guids)
        df.insert(0, 'ID', guids_s)

        df.to_sql("stillinger", conn, if_exists="append", index=False, chunksize=1000)


    sql = """
        select * from stillinger limit 1
          """

    res = pd.read_sql(sql, conn); res
```

Which works great if I want to store all in one .db file. Any suggestions of how to create 11 .db instead of one .db file? Maybe a simple modification on the code, or a more efficient way to convert them?

Is this a reasonable way?:

```
    for year in range(2006,2017,1):
        for file in year: 

            conn=sqlite3.connect('/Users/mo/PBL/arbetsformedlingen/+ str(year)  + '.db')  
            conn.execute('drop table if exists stillinger')

            file = '/Users/mo/PBL/arbetsformedlingen/'  + str(year) + '.json'
            df = pd.read_json(file, lines=True)

            guids = []
            for i in range(0,len(df)):
            guids.append(str(uuid.uuid4()))

            guids_s = pd.Series(guids)
            df.insert(0, 'ID', guids_s)

            df.to_sql("stillinger", conn, if_exists="append", index=False, chunksize=1000)


    sql = """
        select * from stillinger limit 1
          """

    res = pd.read_sql(sql, conn); res
```

Best regards
Mo

Comment: You could move the creation of the database inside the for-loop.

Comment: @ChristianStade-Schuldt I edited the question. Didn't figured out the coding part under comments .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the hint @Christian Stade-Schuldt ! This solved my problem:

```
for year in range(2006,2017,1):
    conn=sqlite3.connect('/Users/mo/PBL/arbetsformedlingen/' + str(year)  + '.db') 
    cur = conn.cursor()
    conn.execute('drop table if exists stillinger')

    file = '/Users/mo/PBL/arbetsformedlingen/' + str(year) + '.json'
    df = pd.read_json(file, lines=True)


    guids = []
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        guids.append(str(uuid.uuid4()))

    guids_s = pd.Series(guids)
    df.insert(0, 'ID', guids_s)

    df.to_sql("stillinger", conn, if_exists="append", index=False, chunksize=1000)
```